# Using Animate with ListPointPlot3D on more than one list

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I have a couple orbits defined which have been mapped into one array as shown:

```
Clear["Global`"];

Off[General::spell, General::spell1, General::infy];

δt = 0.01;
Particles = 5;
CreateParticle[size_] := Module[
  {posrand := RandomReal[{-1.00 size, 1.00 size}],
   velrand := RandomReal[{-0.03 size, 0.03 size}]},
  {{posrand, posrand, posrand},
   {velrand, velrand, velrand}, 1.0/Particles}]

Data = Map[CreateParticle, Range[Particles]];

Positions := Table[Data[[n, 1]], {n, 1, Length[Data]}];
Velocities := Table[Data[[n, 2]], {n, 2, Length[Data]}];

Forces[particle_] := Sum[If[particle != others,
   (1/Particles)/
    Norm[Positions[[others]] - 
      Positions[[particle]]]^3*(Positions[[others]] - 
      Positions[[particle]]), 0],
  {others, Length[Data]}]

Force = Map[Forces, Range[Particles]];

n = 1000;

Clear[Orbit1, Orbit];

Orbit1 = Table[0, {i, n}, {j, Particles}];

Do[{Data[[i, 2]] = Data[[i, 2]] + Force[[i]]*δt,
   Data[[i, 1]] = Data[[i, 1]] + Data[[i, 2]]*δt,
   Forces[particle_] := Sum[If[particle != others,
      (Positions[[others]] - Positions[[particle]])/
       Norm[Positions[[others]] - Positions[[particle]]]^3, 0],
     {others, Length[Data]}],
   Orbit1[[j, i]] = Data[[i, 1]]
   }, {i, 1, Particles}, {j, 1, n}];

Orbit[t_] := Table[Orbit1[[i, t]], {i, 1, n}]

Animate[
ListPointPlot3D[Orbits = Map[Orbit, Range[Particles]]],
{j,1,n,1}]
```

My issue is trying to get [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) to work with [`ListPointPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html). This code works, (the actual outcome of the code is a work in progress, please leave that to me) I just need help figuring out how to get `Animate` to plot the orbits over time.

Comment: `Orbit1` and `Particles` are what?

Comment: See edited question code, sorry about that.

Comment: The code doesn't work, restart your kernel and copy this code and you should see the errors too.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for help. I am just showing where I want to go with it.

Comment: I guess Pickett meant that if you provide us with a working example, you will improve your chances of receiving an answer. By working example, we mean something that we can run with a simple copy-paste, or with minimum hassle. On a quick glance: `Particles` is undefined, and so is `Force`, `Data`, `Positions`...

Comment: Fair enough, I included the rest of my code. Everything works fine. Please read my rephrased question.

Comment: Why bother with Animate when you can use Manipulate? Manipulate is super set of Animate, plus much more functionality. At min, Manipulate=Animate, (click the play botton on the slider, it becomes Animate). But you have better control of things.

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter cause they are essentially the same function with only a select few differences. But I still can't quite figure out how to put them into the Manipulate/Animate function.